# How to set timer on voice note while recording (same as WhatsApp voice message recording feature)?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a chat app which having voice message feature but while recording  couldn't get any feeler or timer like "WhatsApp" so can anybody have this solution 
I tried the code of developer Android but could find such a solution.

```
btn_voice.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
{
 startRecording();
}
else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
{
    stopRecording();
}
return false;
}
});
```

Comment: `timer like "whatsapp"` what does it do/how does it look? You have to show or explain without `like whatsapp`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hanldler

```
 private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
```

then in `startRecording(){starttimer();}`

Then

```
 private void starttimer() {
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    //    customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

    }

 private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "DefaultLocale"})
        public void run() {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            dialTimer.setText("" + mins + ":"+String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"+String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
```

And To stop the timer

```
customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer these ..
Linear Timer is a custom view for Android that enables circular progress animation 
https://github.com/krtkush/LinearTimer